# Decoding a generic decodable type

Tags: swift, codable, combine, decodable

I need to create a generic struct that will hold any decodable type which is returned from the network, so I created something like this:

```
struct NetworkResponse<Wrapped: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var result: Wrapped
}
```

so I can use the decoding method like this:

```
struct MyModel: Decodable {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
  var details: String
}

func getData<R: Decodable>(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<R, Error>
    URLSession.shared
   .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
   .map(\.data)
   .decode(type: NetworkResponse<R>.self, decoder: decoder)
   .map(\.result)
   .eraseToAnyPublisher()

//call site
let url = URL(string: "https://my/Api/Url")!
let models: [MyModel] = getData(url: url)
  .sink {
   //handle value here
}
```

But, I noticed that some responses from the network contains the `result` key, and some others do not:

with result:

```
{
"result": { [ "id": 2, "name": "some name", "details": "some details"] }
}
```

without result:

```
[ "id": 2, "name": "some name", "details": "some details" ]
```

this results in the following error from the `.map(\.result)` publisher because it can't find the `result` key in the returned json:

`(typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)))`

How can I handle either case in the `NetworkResponse` struct in order to avoid such error?

Comment: So you either have the array returned under the `result` key, or you have it returned at the top level?

Comment: yeah totally ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON your posted isn't valid, but I'm assuming it's a typo and it's actually:

```
{ "id": 2, "name": "some name", "details": "some details" }
// or
{ "result": { "id": 2, "name": "some name", "details": "some details" } }
```

<sup>(`{` `}` instead of `[` `]`)</sup>

---

Probably the cleanest is with a manual decoder that can fall back to another type, if the first type fails:

```
struct NetworkResponse<Wrapped> {
    let result: Wrapped
}

extension NetworkResponse: Decodable where Wrapped: Decodable {
    private struct ResultResponse: Decodable {
        let result: Wrapped
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let result = try container.decode(ResultResponse.self)
            self.result = result.result
        } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound, DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            self.result = try container.decode(Wrapped.self)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can fall back within Combine. I would not have gone with this approach, but for completeness-sake:

```
URLSession.shared
   .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
   .map(\.data)
   .flatMap { data in
       Just(data)
         .decode(type: NetworkResponse<R>.self, decoder: decoder)
         .map(\.result)
         .catch { _ in
             Just(data)
                .decode(type: R.self, decoder: decoder)
         }
   }
   .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```